# Having a backend executable communicate with web app on PHP

Tags: java, php, c++, web-applications, backend

Suppose my web app is written in PHP & Mysql on the standard LAMP stack etc...and I have some uber awesome and complex algorithm compiled as an executable in some other desktop programming language such as C++, Java, or C running in the backend....how would I go about passing data and information between the PHP script on the webapp and the running backend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have no idea what you are doing, but have you looked at exec() system() etc?

Comment: if i understand it, those commands would actually run the program itself....but what if the program is already running in the background and I just want to communicate with it in PHP?

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [writing php extensions](http://www.tuxradar.com/practicalphp/20/1/0) .